# Visual Studio 2013 Tools for GIT - cannot publish an unpublished branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to use an existing GIT setup within VS2013 using Tools for Git extension.

I believe the repositories and remotes are setup correctly because I can do what I need to using GitShell -- this has not presented any difficulties.

I have a local repository and inside of Team Explorer the `master` branch is shown as an *Unpublished Branch*.  When I right-click and choose *Publish Branch* a progress bar is displayed briefly and then the message:

> Successfully published branch master to .

(please note the period '.' at the end)

But the branch remains in the *Unpublished Branch* section.  Repeated attempts produce the same non-result.

[image]

What is wrong here?  What can do I break out of this catch-22?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem was the result of a incorrect / partial Git configuration.

In my Git configuration file, the `remote` definition for `origin` did not have any `fetch` entry.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://DM-BUILD/git/StarSchemaMetadata.git

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

With the fetch entry was added as shown here:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://DM-BUILD/git/StarSchemaMetadata.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

The configuration problem has been corrected and now I can successfully *Publish* an *Unpublished Branch* using VS Tools for Git extension.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was [branch "master"] entry missing, adding it solved VS2013 syncing issues.

Comment: To solve the problem from the command line: git branch -u origin/[branchname]. Make sure you are already on [branchname], and replace it with the name of your branch of course (master by default). This will set the current branch to track the remote branch origin/[branch].

Comment: All three of the projects that I've pulled from GitHub are missing the [branch "master"] section.

Comment: This helped me, thanks.  I think this happens if you initially clone using a tool other than VS.